# What is the difference between PublishSubject and PublishRelay in RxSwift?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-swift

I am new to RxSwift programming.
I am confused between the two while coding. Which one should be used to store datasource of table and how to decide that ?

Comment: I think BehaviorRelay makes more sense than PublishSubject or PublishRelay as your table data source.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- A PublishSubject can emit an error or completed event while a PublishRelay cannot.
- A PublishSubject conforms to the ObserverType protocol while the PublishRelay does not.

Another important point that was alluded to by @RobMayoff in his comment. Neither a PublishSubject nor a PublishRelay stores state, so neither of them are a good idea to "store datasource of table".

Fortunately, you don't need to store the state yourself because the DataSource object that the `items` operator creates internally stores it.

In other words, you don't need to use a Subject *or* Relay (of any sort) to feed a table view. Just use an Observable.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the interface to `PublishRelay` you can see that it wraps a `PublishSubject` but it hides this from its interface. So you can only send it `accept(_ event: Element)` which means you cannot send it `error` or `completed` Events only next elements.

```
    public final class PublishRelay<Element>: ObservableType {
    private let subject: PublishSubject<Element>
    
    // Accepts `event` and emits it to subscribers
    public func accept(_ event: Element) {
        self.subject.onNext(event)
    }
    
    /// Initializes with internal empty subject.
    public init() {
        self.subject = PublishSubject()
    }

    //...
}
```

Anyhow, if you look at examples of tableview using `RxCocoa` they just wrap an array as an Observable usually using `Just` or `create` that you then pass to the tableview using RxCocoa's interface. You don't really want a Subject just a plain observable.